Python: import module from gzip file
I have Python module 'common_types' in file: /path/common_types.py.gz
I want to import it in my script:
 import common_types

I tried:
 importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("common_types", "/path/common_types.py.gz")

But it doesn't accept .gz
For now I settled with ugly solution I don't like:
f_in = gzip.open("/path/common_types.py.gz", "rt")
f_out = open("/path/common_types.py")
f_out.write(f_in.read())
f_out.close()


Importing from gzip is not supported.
The format for compressed python packages is Zip, not GZip.
See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html
